# Dont apply rule when url starts with a specific word

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([^-]+)-([^&]+)$ lala.php?type=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L]
```

But I also have:

```
RewriteRule ^testpage/([^-]+)-([^&]+)$ lala.php?type=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L]
```

The first rule overwrites the second rule. Is there a possibility to say smth like: Apply the first rule when ([a-z]+) is not "testpage"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^testpage/([^-]+)-([^&]+)$ lala.php?type=$1&id=$2&title=INVALID-Back-reference [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([^-]+)-([^&]+)$ lala.php?type=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L]
```

However, The first rule has a little problem because it has two back-reference and you have used three! 
you should remove one of them!

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this fix for urls without the www subdomaind

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.|api\.)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This checks whether the url has the www. prefix or the api. prefix. When neither one is the case. It will add the www. subdomain prefix. You situation me be a little different, but the same method applies.